# Who am I ? Batman fans will know this

Tags: riddle, language

> Who AM I?
>   What AM I?
>   If you hold, I leave,
>   I am in you, but I hide very well,
>   Even BATMAN  wants me, and also you,
>   Nobody has ever seen me, but I am always with you - Summer, winter, or rainy.
>   But if you choose to leave me, it is not a bye from you, but a last bye from me.
>   We never meet again...

Comment: I feel like fits well when read in a Cookie Monster voice.

Comment: Who am I? Who am *I*? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xs2tg9MVhTE

Comment: @n_palum..lol..wait for the answer....

Comment: may be this question is limited to india..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of any Batman links to my answer so I'm not sure if it's right but this is the best I could come up with.

Answer:

> breath

Clue 1

> "If you hold I leave": You can only hold your breath for so long before it leaves

Clue 2

> "I am in you, but I hide very well": Breath is in everyone but is unseen

Clue 3

> "Nobody has ever seen me, but I am always with you": Can't see breath (unless its cold I guess) and breath is always with you.

Clue 4

> "But if you choose to leave me, it is not a bye from you, but a last bye from me. We never meet again..."  When you die your last breath is the last.  You never breathe again.

Comment: Some what related but not the answer..

Answer (score -1):

> Answer is ATMA (meaning soul )

If you hold, I leave,

> If hold your breath ,you die.

I am in you, but I hide very well,

> we have atma but don't know where it is ..

Even BATMAN wants me, and also you,

> B **ATMA** N has it ...

Nobody has ever seen me, but I am always with you - Summer, winter, or rainy.
But if you choose to leave me, it is not a bye from you, but a last bye from me.
We never meet again...

> once we die ATMA is freed and body is left behind.

Comment: The answer is far off from what the riddle says. e.g. *Even BATMAN wants me, and also you,* - This is just not right. It could have been *Even BATMAN has it* and I don't get the other part. I don't get like 99% of how it fits ..the things like the seasons made it more obscure. Sorry, just my opinion. (Also, I am from India and know what Atma means) :) IMO, *breath* is a better fit.